# Как лучше всего структурировать код в py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, модули

У меня есть простой бот для VK. Когда человек пишет ему, бот отвечает на это сообщением, в котором содержится главное меню. Из главного меню человек может перейти в настройки. Каждое такое сообщение бота я обернул в функции. Например, функция для показа главного меню называется `show_main_menu`, настроек - `show_settings`. Все эти функции объявлены и используются в файле bot.py.

Хотелось бы сделать так, чтобы у каждой функции был свой отдельный .py файл, который я бы мог импортировать в bot.py и там использовать ее.

Вот пример кода bot.py:

```
import random
import vk_api
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType

users = []
token = "my_token"
group_id = 0012300
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)

def user_init():
    users.append(user_id)
    # other code...

def show_main_menu():
    user_init()
    vk.messages.send(
        user_id = user_id,
        message = "[1] Показать настройки",
        random_id = random.random()
    )

def show_settings():
     settings = "*какие-то настройки*"
     vk.messages.send(
         user_id = user_id,
         message = "Ваши настройки: {user_settings}".format(
             user_settings = settings
         ),
         random_id = random.random()
)

def quit():
    vk.messages.send(
        user_id = user_id,
        message = "Пока "
        random_id = random.random()
    )

longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, group_id)
vk = vk_session.get_api()
# Комментарии для тех, кто не работал с vk_api.py
# Смотрю каждое событие
for event in longpoll.listen():
    # Если пришло новое сообщение
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        # Если сообщение пришло в ЛС бота, а не в беседу (у бесед peer_id > 2000000000)
        if event.object.message["peer_id"] < 2000000000:
            # Беру текст сообщения и id человека, который его написал
            message = event.object.message['text']
            user_id = event.object.message['from_id']
            if message == '❌':
                quit()
            elif message == 'Старт':
                show_main_menu()
            elif message == '1':
                show_settings()
```

Т.е. в данном примере я хотел бы перенести все функции (user_init, show_main_menu, show_settings, quit) в папку functions, внутри которой будут находится соответствующие файлы(user_init.py, show_main_menu.py, show_settings.py, quit.py), а после импортировать их в bot.py. Принято ли так структурировать проекты в Python? И если да, то как мне это сделать?

С питоном работал очень мало, поэтому буду рад любым замечаниям :).

Comment: В простейшем случае - просто создаете файлы, кладете их рядом с основным скриптом, в основном скрипте их импортируете. Но в вашем случае вообще нет особого смысла настолько сильно дробить. В отдельные модули имеет смысл выносить несколько функций, связанных общими задачами, или целые классы, но каждую функцию в отдельный модуль нет смысла складывать.

Answer (score 0):

Первые же ссылки в Гуугл совершенно неожидано описывают, как правильно делать то, что вы задумали.

https://devpractice.ru/python-lesson-13-modules-and-packages/

https://ru.hexlet.io/blog/posts/likbez-po-paketam-i-shpargalka-po-modulyam-v-python

https://tehnojam.ru/category/development/sozdaem-svoj-paket-python.html

https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/rabota-s-modulyami-sozdanie-podklyuchenie-instrukciyami-import-i-from.html

А если вам лень лезть в Гуугл, то эта тема неплохо раскрыта в любой книге по Python - от Лутца дп Любановича.

Или вы принципиально не пользуетесь внешними источникам?

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/481728)

Comment: Ссылка на один из ответов по прошествии какого-то достаточно большого промежутка времени может, конечно, стать недействительной. Но переписывать тут классические учебники в кратком изложении - тоже не комильфо.

Comment: ok....................